# Error sending a notification to a specific user, using OneSignal on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onesignal

When trying to send a notification to a specific user, it generates an error.
I don't understand what's going on, since I'm following the documentation.

Tests were done on Android device.

Code that sends the notification:

```
public static void SendNotification(string title, string message, string senderId){
    extraMessage = "Waiting to get a OneSignal userId. Uncomment OneSignal.SetLogLevel in the Start method if it hangs here to debug the issue.";
    Debug.Log($"OneSignalExtra: {extraMessage}");
    OneSignal.IdsAvailable((userId, pushToken) => {
        if (pushToken != null) {
            var userIdNotify = senderId;

            var notification = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            notification["contents"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"pt", title} };
            notification["headings"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"pt", message} };
            notification["template_id"] = "my template id";
            // Send notification to this device.
            notification["include_player_ids"] = new List<string>() { userIdNotify };
            OneSignal.PostNotification(notification, (responseSuccess) => {
                extraMessage = "Notification posted successful! Delayed by about 30 secounds to give you time to press the home button to see a notification vs an in-app alert.\n" + Json.Serialize(responseSuccess);
                Debug.Log($"OneSignalExtra: {extraMessage}");
            }, (responseFailure) => {
                extraMessage = "Notification failed to post:\n" + Json.Serialize(responseFailure);
                Debug.Log($"OneSignalExtra: {extraMessage}");
            });
        } else {
            extraMessage = "ERROR: Device is not registered.";
        }
        print(extraMessage);
    }

    );
}
```

Error obtained after trying to send:

12-09 14:18:25.493: E/Unity(28828): Exception Exception: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
12-09 14:18:25.493: E/Unity(28828): OneSignal.isValidSuccessFailureDelegate (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] jsonObject) (at <6d52692b70b2475ca1c61c8ae70ef58a>:0) 12-09 14:18:25.493: E/Unity(28828): OneSignal.onPostNotificationFailed (System.String jsonString) (at <6d52692b70b2475ca1c61c8ae70ef58a>:0) 12-09 14:18:25.493: E/Unity(28828):   12-09 14:18:25.493: E/Unity(28828): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35) 12-09 14:18:25.502: E/Unity(28828): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 12-09 14:18:25.502: E/Unity(28828):   at OneSignal.isValidSuccessFailureDelegate (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] jsonObject) [0x00026] in <6d52692b70b2475ca1c61c8ae70ef58a>:0
12-09 14:18:25.502: E/Unity(28828):   at OneSignal.onPostNotificationFailed (System.String jsonString) [0x00015] in <6d52692b70b2475ca1c61c8ae70ef58a>:0
12-09 14:18:25.502: E/Unity(28828):
12-09 14:18:25.502: E/Unity(28828): (Filename: <6d52692b70b2475ca1c61c8ae70ef58a> Line: 0)

I know that the error happens from OneSignal.PostNotification.

Comment: The key is not being found in the dictionary.  Where is the data loaded in the dictionary?  Which line of code is failing?

Comment: Why is this happening? Because I inform the key and the value. What I could see is that the error is generated from OneSignal.PostNotification (notification, (responseSuccess) => {

Comment: I checked the notification that should be sent, it looks like this:
{
 "contents":{"pt":"Title Message"},
 "headings":{"pt":"Body Message"},
 "template_id":"My code template",
 "include_player_ids":["My user ID"]
}

Comment: What data is in the dictionary?  Is the key that you are using in the dictionary?

Comment: It was supposed to be this:
{
 "contents":{"pt":"Title Message"},
 "headings":{"pt":"Body Message"},
 "template_id":"My code template",
 "include_player_ids":["My user ID"]
}

Comment: See following : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-web-push#debugging-not-receiving-chrome-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that OneSignal requires having a field where I say the title and the message in English. In my case it is English and Portuguese, and just putting it as Portuguese would make me an error.

The template created in OneSignal is also in English and Portuguese.

The code looks like this:

```
public static void SendNotification(string title, string message, string senderId){
extraMessage = "Waiting to get a OneSignal userId. Uncomment OneSignal.SetLogLevel in the Start method if it hangs here to debug the issue.";
OneSignal.IdsAvailable((userId, pushToken) => {
    if (pushToken != null) {
        var userIdNotify = senderId;

        var notification = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        notification["headings"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"pt", title}, { "en", title } };
        notification["contents"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"pt", message}, { "en", message } };
        notification["include_player_ids"] = new List<string>() { userIdNotify };
        
        notification["template_id"] = "my code template";
        
        // Send notification to this device.
        
        OneSignal.PostNotification(notification, (responseSuccess) => {
            extraMessage = "Notification posted successful! Delayed by about 30 secounds to give you time to press the home button to see a notification vs an in-app alert.\n" + Json.Serialize(responseSuccess);
        }, (responseFailure) => {
            extraMessage = "Notification failed to post:\n" + Json.Serialize(responseFailure);
        });
    } else {
        extraMessage = "ERROR: Device is not registered.";
    }
    print(extraMessage);
}

);
```

}